# Facebook External Widget development with a single app

Tags: facebook, widget

We're trying to develop a widget that uses Facebook APIs and other websites (e.g different domains) could embed. We do not want every website to create it's on Facebook app but we'd like everyone using this widget to be connected to our Facebook app.
The problem is that Facebook seems to authenticate only a specific domain for an app (Canvas URL).
Ideas?
Guy

Update: I just realized that for Facebook server API as long as I set the redirect_uri to a valid URL (as defined by the site url) then everything is OK. So I can let my widget call the login and set the redirect_uri to some page we hold on our server that will communicate with the origin. So far so good. Now the problem that remains is **whether there's a way to do it  using the Facebook JS sdk rather then having to invent the wheel**. From what I see there I could find a way to make the JS SDK not use the window.location.href. Ideas?

Comment: get the user's friends, post to the user's wall etc

Answer (score 0):

you just need to create the app, then from the profile site of your app there is an link to let users add the app to their page. (this is also possible via a special link (see the docs))

but be aware, one page can only include your app once. so if you like your "customers" to have your app multiple times on the same page you have to create multiple apps but point the canvas and tab url to the same script.
The other way would be to add child applications directly for the user, so you can let your customers even set a customized icon. This is hard to code couse you have to use old apis (newer one doesnt support the functions anymore) and there is none to null documentation for it. (I have such an app running, if you want to see some examples drop me a note)

Comment: Thanks but I think my question may have not been clear enough. We're developing a widget that works with Facebook APIs, it would be embedded on different *websites* (e.g. different domains) not on different Facebook pages